# Jquery div filtering based on click event

Tags: jquery

Here i'm having a script that which filters the div elements.

[Working Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/X6gQz/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="#" data-category-type="4380" data-category-name="jet">4380</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="4620" data-category-name="air">4620</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="5000" data-category-name="india">5000</a>

</div>
<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="4380" data-category-name="jet">4380.</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="4620" data-category-name="air">4620.</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="5000" data-category-name="india">5000.</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="4380" data-category-name="jet">4380.</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
    var nam = $(this).data('categoryName');
    $('#Categories > div').hide();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();

});
```

here, i'm checking only one condition (data-category-type),

But here, i want to check the both conditions

1. data-category-type
2. data-category-name

How can i achieve this , can anyone help me out please.

**EDIT**
Here i have one more question, how can i show all div elements (if i click on)

```
<a href="">Show all</a>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append one more condition like

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
    var nam = $(this).data('categoryName');
    $('#Categories > div').hide();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"][data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KTZPy/)

Also check

```
var divs = $('#Categories > div');
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var cat = $this.data('categoryType');
    var nam = $this.data('categoryName');
    divs.filter(':visible').hide();
    divs.filter('[data-category-type="'+cat+'"][data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KTZPy/2/)

Comment: ya got it but, this <a href="#">Show all</a> will be outside of div.nav then??